# Group and rename pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pythons Pandas, I have a dataframe where one column holds a group called "code" and another column holds notes for that group. Each occurrence of those groups may have different notes.
How to rename the groups by selecting the first occurrence of the note in that group?

Example:

IN:

```
CODE   NOTE
A      Banana
B      Cola
A      Apple
B      Fanta
C      Toy
```

Out:

```
CODE     NOTE
Banana   Banana
Cola     Cola
Banana   Apple
Cola     Fanta
Toy      Toy
```

So far, I have this code to group and display code, count, and note:

```
df.groupby('code').note.agg(['count', 'first']).sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `drop_duplicates` and then `map` `NOTE` to `CODE`:

```
df['CODE'] = df.CODE.map(df.drop_duplicates('CODE').set_index('CODE').NOTE)
```

Or,

```
df['CODE'] = df.CODE.replace(df.drop_duplicates('CODE').set_index('CODE').NOTE)
```

Alternatively,

```
mapper = df.drop_duplicates('CODE').set_index('CODE').NOTE.to_dict()
df['CODE'] = df['CODE'].map(mapper)
```

```
df

     CODE    NOTE
0  Banana  Banana
1    Cola    Cola
2  Banana   Apple
3    Cola   Fanta
4     Toy     Toy
```

Note; `map` is magnitudes of order faster than `replace`, but both of them work the same.